# HttpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync don't deserialize JSON when it come from CreateErrorResponse

Tags: c#, json

if i return from my selfhosted webapi

```
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "YAY");
```

everything is fine.. so i can read it like that:

```
var responseStr = await Client.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();
and then make something like "MessageBox.Show(responseStr);
```

if i return

```
Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "something went wrong!");
```

and i read it out the same way or even with(doesn't matter how):

```
Client.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

the string is not deserialized and i get an error when trying to parse / read as string.

if i read it as object .. it's fine.. but i can't perform object.ToString();
i get errors..

why? and how to fix it?

Comment: Please explain _"the string is not deserialized and i get an error when trying to parse / read as string"_. Preferably show the code that does this and the exact exception you get. I think the error response doesn't contain a body, so `Content.Read...()` won't return anything.

Comment: i mean not deserialized from json to string

Comment: so if that is true that it doesn't contain a body, then CreateErrorResponse isn't creating a response body?

Comment: oh the problem was that i was returning the HttpStatusCode.NotFound .. that seams to not create a body. you helped me out thank you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found that there were extra '\' and '"' in the returned JSON.
So before I serialize back to an object, I needed to remove the extra chars.

e.g.

```
string jsonString = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                                               .Result
                                               .Replace("\\", "")
                                               .Trim(new char[1] { '"' });

List<VwAisItemMaster> vwAisItemMasterList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<VwAisItemMaster>>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved me

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is just to fix the issue when creating the response in the webapi method. 
Note the type in the CreateResponse method.

```
IList<VwItemMaster> vwItemMasterList = this.itemMastersGetByUpc(unitOfWork, upc);

HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = this.Request.CreateResponse<IList<VwItemMaster>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, vwItemMasterList);

httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
```